# Replace the n first occurrences of a letter

Tags: ruby, regex, string, replace

I'd like to modify the n first occurrences of a letter in a ruby string.

For example :

```
> "abcabcabcabc".some_magic_method("a", "0", 3)
=> "0bc0bc0bcabc"
```

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something but I'm not able to find an easy way! Maybe with regexes ?

Comment: Easiest way is to see if there is a replacement limit parameter using regex. Then find 'a' replace '0'.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the basic split/join method:

```
"abcabcabcabc".split('a', 4).join('0')
```

Note that the split limit must be: *number of replacements + 1*

Answer (score 2):

My first idea was:

```
3.times.inject("abcabcabcabc") { |str, _| str.sub!('a','0') }
```

But I like Casimir's answer more, especially because this solution is only `O(mn)`.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work when one wants to sub `a` with `aa`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another single-pass method:

```
class String
  def some_magic_method(c_before, c_after, ntimes)
    gsub(/#{c_before}/) { ntimes -= 1; (ntimes>=0) ? c_after : c_before }
  end
end

"abcabcabcabc".some_magic_method('a', '0', 3)
  #=> "0bc0bc0bcabc"

"abcabcabcabc".some_magic_method('ab', 'xyz', 2)
  #=> "xyzcxyzcabcabc"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do the simple thing:

```
str = "abcabcabcabc"
3.times { str.sub!("a", "0") }
str # => "0bc0bc0bcabc"
```

If you have to have a method:

```
class String
  def some_magic_method(n, target, replacement)
    n.times { self.sub!(target, replacement) }
    self
  end
end

str = "abcabcabcabc"
str.some_magic_method(3, 'a', '0') # => "0bc0bc0bcabc"
```

Comment: No, but that wasn't a requirement.

Comment: Yes, not required in the question, but I feel that the question can have a generalization.